# Moving Key Frames All Together One Time

Tags: animation

I always get this problem of moving all the keyframes all together. I have to go by each object and count the frames which is very difficult and time consuming.

My question is...Is there a way to select all objects and move all their KEYFRAMES at once in the timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dopesheet window is what you are looking for, it has a button with which you can manipulate only selected objects.

[image]

Comment: thanks josh.....exactly what i needed